# How do I query GCP Search APIs asynchronously from an App Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-search-api, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I need to search my App Engine indexed documents using the Search API. From what I can tell, the Search API can only be referenced with the google.appengine APIs for the standard environment.

My problem is that some hydrating, flushing, and querying takes longer than 60 seconds. I need to return a response from app engine, continue processing the request in the background, then publish the results to Pub/Sub. However, I can spawn threads or use background_thread in the standard environment. I'd switch to the flexible environment, but I cannot use the Python Search API library.

Is my only option to switch to the flex environment, and use REST APIs?

Comment: Have you try `index.search_async()`?

Comment: I don't think that will work.

Let's say I have to delete 16,000 docs, I then need to pause my code for a minute after 15,000 before processing the remaining docs due to the 15,000 operations/minute limit.

Comment: That delete operation limit in Search is always 15000/min no matter which environment you are using, what you can do is rather contact google to upgrade it or establish the delete job to cloud task (work independently and still have 15000 limit) and publish the data to Pub/Sub **first**. If second one is acceptable, I can share an example.

Comment: Sure! Would you mind sharing an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use app engine task queue, which is a task scheduler for queuing pending tasks for another app engine to do it as App engine is single thread engine.

For example,

**1. Set up a new service to handle task (OPTIONAL)**

Setup a yaml call `newtaskworker.yaml` which is similar to your `app.yaml`, as you may want another service to do the task not the original one.

Only difference is remember to add a service name for it, `service: newtaskworker`

Remember to deploy it by `gcloud app deploy newtaskworker.yaml`

**2. Set up a queue**

Read [How to Create new queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-push-queues), generally speak you need a `queue.yaml` for queuing the tasks. Remember to deploy it by `gcloud app deploy queue.yaml`

```
queue:
- name: queue_name
  rate: 20/s #You may limit the speed of *START* new task here
  bucket_size: 40
  max_concurrent_requests: 10 #This is limited by your max_instances allowed in newtaskworker.yaml, you may simply omit it
```

**3. Finally your code**

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

#/deleteTask
class DeleteTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        paramA      = self.request.get('paramA')
        paramB      = self.request.get('paramB')
        #your Search delete here

class GetPostDataTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):   
        #If you don't want to use a new service, simply use 'default` in target.
        #Your Go to Pub/Sub work here.
        taskqueue.add(queue_name='queue_name', url='/deleteTask', method='GET', params={'paramA': 1, 'paramB': 2}, target='newtaskworker')
```

If nothing goes wrong, you can find your task in Console -> Tools -> Cloud Task

Comment: Wow. I think this solves my problem. I'll let you know tomorrow after I try it out. Thanks!!!